# JSP Java Uploading file issue with io.common

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, apache-commons-io

I have an issue with the common-io-2.4, where the FileItemFactory doesn't seem to have the method setReposity. I've used the code from the Apache website ([Apache File Upload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html)). It's rather infuriating, as I've seen other people use it an have no issues. I've included the jar file in my project, and i don't get errors with other objects from the library, just that one.
It's as if it's not got all of the methods.

Any ideas? Here is my code, and I'm writing it in Netbeans

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileItem;

import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;


/**
 *
 * @author Harry
 */
public class FileUpload extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> and
     * <code>POST</code> methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        
        if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){ // checks if it is an upload request;
            // Create a factory for disk-based file items
            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            
            // Configure a repository (to ensure a secure temp location is used)
            ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
            File repository = (File) servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
            factory.setReposity(repository);
           

            // Create a new file upload handler
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            try{
                // Parse the request
               List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);  // this creates fileItems, which i then need to loop through and write each one to the file. 
               
               
            }catch(FileUploadException ex){
                System.out.println("Failed to upload file");
            }
            
            
        }
        else{
            response.sendRedirect("UserHome.jsp");
        }
        
    }
```

this object

FileItemFactory

doesn't seem to have the method setReposity, or many other methods. I don't know why?

Maybe I'm just missing something simple?
Any help would be great! Cheers!

Comment: You tell us you have issues, but not which ones. Post stack traces.

Comment: I've added more information. It won't compile, due to the it not having the methods attached to the FileItemFactory. I'm at a loss as to why.

Answer (score 0):

Found that the example used FileItemFactory, yet found that if you switch it to the DiskFileItemFactory, you have access to the methods.

Comment: I've been through the Commons File Upload documentation and fixed the one place I found where this error occurred. The updated documentation will be included in 1.3.1 onwards.